# JMeter - RegEx for URL not resolving as Path variable

Tags: jmeter

New to JMeter. Running into an issue; every tutorial, video and questions surrounding it haven't seemed to point me in the right direction yet. Hoping to find some help to get over this hump.

Trying to build a test plan to be used for load testing. The site uses dynamically generated URLs and I'm having trouble getting these URLs used in the requests.

After login we encounter the first dynamically generated URL.
I've inserted a Regular Expression Post Processor on the thread.

```
Apply to: Main sample and sub-samples
Field to check: Response Message
Reference Name: baseURL
Regular Expression: V.baseURL = "(.+?)"
Template: $1$
```

When I test the expression in RegExp Tester I'm receiving results:

```
Match count: 1

    Match[1][0]=V.baseURL = "/site_name/servlet/site_nameb/action/Dispatcher/nocacheid/1463414114154/hsid/b316686f3e47f40e3f2abfc5ee3d4e5e"  
    Match[1][1]=/site_name/servlet/site_nameb/action/Dispatcher/nocacheid/1463414114154/hsid/b316686f3e47f40e3f2abfc5ee3d4e5e
```

In the subsequent thread HTTP Request I've entered the variable *${baseURL}* in **Path**

When I run the test plan I'm getting a syntax exception b/c it's not resolving the variable. The Path is using ${baseURL} in place of the returned value from the Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

> Field to check: **Response Message**

Response Message for successful request will be just `OK`

[image: Response Message]

Change "Field to Check" to **Body** and it should start working as expected.

References:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](http://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks @dmitri-t - `Body (unescaped)` was the ticket punch for my situation. I was focused on Response data. Thanks for the help.